# Double posts: close the older or newer one?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I sometimes come across double posts (the exact same question, same user, posted within a short time). An example is this: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298411/how-to-include-html-contents-from-another-site-i-have-access-to-both-sites), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298418/how-to-include-html-contents-from-another-site-i-have-access-to-both-sites), posted with a minute or two between them. My reaction was to vote to close the newer of the two questions, while I can see that someone voted to close the older of them. What would be the preferred way here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One had an upvote, so I deleted the other one.

In general, just flag it for moderator attention. We can merge or delete as necessary.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

Answer (score 1):

In this case it really doesn't matter, as the posts contain the exact same text. In this case I would close the one without votes (as there's one already with a vote). In another case maybe it's better to keep the last one (maybe there are already some changes in the text).
But as it is here, it really doesn't matter. Maybe the better option is to flag it for moderator attention (like mentioned by [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/double-posts-close-the-older-or-newer-one/15383#15383)) and the first mod that passes by it, will have to decide ;-)

Comment: Sounds sensible to vote to close the one without upvotes (there was no upvote when I voted to close)