# Why did an older, more general question get closed in favor of a newer one?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

This question [Why do search engines ignore symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737172/why-do-search-engines-ignore-symbols) was closed in favor of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098078/why-is-it-so-hard-to-search-for-the-symbol-via-google.

So why did the first one get closed instead of the second one, if it's a more general and older question than the second one? I also don't think the second one is any better content-wise.

Comment: See [Opinions on closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question).

Comment: Both are grossly off-topic.

Comment: It's not more "grossly off-topic" than your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274009/how-to-get-started-writing-ical-plugins)... Read the [freaking FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). "if your question generally covers **a software algorithm**, **matters that are unique to the programming profession** then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that the closure doesn't make a lot of sense. The general question is definitely better in this case.

I voted to reopen the more general question and to close the more specific one as its duplicate.